# Finding all letters of a word in a textfile

Tags: python

I've got a giant English words dictionary and I'm trying to get all the words that contain the same letters of another word, for example, if given aplep, I want it to give apple or if given applej it should be apple as well, I've tried gaining all the permutations from the word but then it becomes unreasonable for big words, anyone has any thoughts?

EDIT: The dictionary is a txt file with line delimiter

Thanks.

Comment: What format is the dictionary?

Comment: just compare sorted versions

Comment: the dictionary is a txt file

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I had that thought but I have a question: if OP wants to check subsets, doesn't this change things?

Comment: @S.Haviv yes, comma delimited, space delimited, line delimited?

Comment: line delimited.

Comment: "i've tried x". Please supply your code.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output? Is it 1 list, in which you need to find all the couples, or is it a list, where afterwards you ask for the similarities for & word

Comment: @Colin I answered but that doesn't work. I think it's rather difficult to achieve. maybe with collections.Counter...

Answer (score 2):

You could count the letters of each word and determine if the search word is a subset as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

def subset(c1, c2):
    for c, count in c1.items():
        if 0 < count > c2[c]:
            return False
    return True

words = ['apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'applej', 'appppppplllllleeee', 'aple']
find_word = Counter('aplep')

for word in words:
    if subset(find_word, Counter(word)):
        print word
```

This would display three matches:

```
apple
applej
appppppplllllleeee
```

---

To read your list of words from a file called `words.txt`, assuming that each word is on its own line:

```
with open('words.txt') as f_input:
    words = f_input.read().splitlines()

find_word = Counter('aplep')

for word in words:
    if subset(find_word, Counter(word)):
        print word
```

Comment: "aple" should match too.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate on @Jean-FrançoisFabre's answer.

You can store the sorted words in a sort of prefix tree, a data structure that has the sorted words in leaves and the path to a word is an increasing prefix of those words. 
For example: if you have 'abc' and 'abd' in your dictionary the structure would look like

`a
  \
  ab
 / \
abc abd`

If you want all words containing 'ab' you traverse the tree, and use all following nodes as keys in a dictionary to find the unsorted words

Answer (score 0):

something like this? using set to get all permutations

```
given_word = "apple"
list_of_all_words_in_dictionary = ["applepie", "anapple"]

given_word = set(given_word )
for word in list_of_all_words_in_dictionary:
    if given_word.issubset(set(word)):
        #do something
```

the limitation of the idea is that even words like "aple" will pass the test, if you only want "apple" / "alepp" to pass the test and don't want "aple", then maybe instead of using the set() to get the word char set, using a custom function count the number of each char first:

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd

def count_char(word):
    word_dict = dd(word)
    for char in word:
        word_dict[char] += 1
    return word_dict.items()
```

Comment: You mean `for word in list_of_all_words_in_dictionary:`. Your solution would also match `aple`.

Comment: There's a problem because apple would become {'l', 'e', 'a', 'p'} and we lose the second 'p'

Comment: @MartinEvans didn't notice that, thx

Answer (score 0):

Read your dictionary, for each word  word1, read your dictionary again, for each word word2

```
if word1.strip(word2) == '':
  print word1 " contains only letters from " word2
```